# look and feel of html5 applications?

Tags: css, theme

Where can I find a theme kit to use for my websites, to skin them as html5 applications...

Sorry, I dunno how to explain myself.. I see this style in new web applications:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are you asking? HTML5 has nothing to do with a particular skin or look. You can make an HTML5 site look and feel however you want just like you can make a non-HTML5 site look and feel however you want. Grooveshark didn't use a "theme kit" for their site. They hired a professional interface designer to create the look they wanted.

Comment: Has your question been answered here by Lese or picxelplay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search Google for things like:
**gui themes**
**gui templates**
**free gui templates**
**free gui themes**
Also, I am pretty sure one of the **Envato** family of websites has gui templates and such. Most likely ThemeForest maybe??

Comment: thanks! ok, this helps. But I couldn't find gui themes.. mostly are generic themes for websites. Do you know where i can find such specific category of themes ?

Comment: I found this on a quick search: http://webguitemplates.com. Also try a search of "psd gui." Also go to http://themeforest.net, and type in admin, or admin templates. Also http://visionwidget.com/toolz/4-design/488-free-gui-psd-elements.html.  I have seen tons and tons of free icon, bar, and header background sets around the web. Also, go to http://smashingmagazine.com, and type in "gui" or "wireframe".  I have seen gui and wireframe themes and gui mockup sites on smashing.  You might have to mix and match a bunch to get the look you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for styled GUI widgets? Try using the widgets in [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). You can use a theme from their Gallery, or create your own color scheme using their ThemeRoller. Either way, the library provides you with "modern" looking interface controls (tabs, sliders, date pickers, buttons, etc). There are also other widget frameworks out there, such as [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) from Yahoo.

Assuming that I am understanding the intent of your question, that's the best answer I can give other than hire a web designer. As Lese pointed out, this isn't really an HTML5 thing, and most sites are achieving it via hard working designers. These frameworks don't really provide templates that you can just apply to an existing page. They are somewhat skinnable building blocks that you can use as part of a larger site design.

Answer (score 0):

It is the CSS that provides that skin for HTML, not HTML itself. HTML is about structure while CSS is about visual presentation. You can clearly have that look with just HTML 3.2 - really!